# How to run the same commands over all the files in the entire folder and export numerous text files?

Tags: r, loops, file, text

I would like to run the same commands over all the pdf documents within the entire folder. This is to extract something from each of the files within the same folder and write them into multiple text files. The structure looks like this.

```
file1_text <- readtext("folder/file1.pdf", 
                       encoding = "UTF-8")
file1_text1 <- file1_text[1,2]
John <- str_extract_all(file1_text1,"John.*?hello")
writeLines(paste(unlist(John),collapse=""),con="file1John.txt")
Peter <- str_extract_all(file1_text1,"Peter.*?good morning")
writeLines(paste(unlist(Peter),collapse=""),con="file1Peter.txt")
```

Suppose there are 3 files within the folder, namely file1, file 2, file3. John and Peter should have their respective txt file output for each of the three files. I would like to have the txt file output with the following names.

```
file1John.txt

file1Peter.txt

file2John.txt

file2Peter.txt

file3John.txt

file3Peter.txt
```

The names of the file have to be different and identifiable by having different names as above. May I ask how I can deal with this (e.g. by writing loop)? Sorry that I am not too familiar with loop.

Many thanks.

Comment: @akrun sorry what I meant by names would be the outputs set out above. e.g. file1John.txt, file1Peter.txt and so on. Thanks so much!

Comment: Known already. I will write a separate line of command to tease out each text file associated with every person (John, Peter, e.t.c.)